# How do I correct a fatal error for a custom field I've coded in my functions file?

Tags: wordpress, function, genesis

I'm using **Genesis** and a child theme.

I've read articles in the `WordPress Codex` and browsed several blog posts, but I'm not finding a solution. I followed an answer found in `StackOverflow`, but I'm wondering if I first need to activate custom fields. I haven't done anything other than create the keys and values and add the below code to my `functions.php` file.

These are the keys: **question** and **link**. The idea is to pose a question to my blog readers at the end of each blog post, related to the content, and for the question to display as a link. The link will take readers to my Facebook page I create for that blog post. It's basically an off-site comments system.

**This is the code I'm using:**

```
add_action('genesis_entry_content', 'moose_question');
 function moose_question() {
     $question = get_field('question', $post_id);
     $link = get_field('link', $post_id);
     echo '<div class="moose-question">';
     echo '<a href="$link">$question</a>';
     echo '</div>';
    }
```

Is `get_field` the correct call to use? Is `$post_id` required? It just seems that since this is being placed in the blog post loop, it should know to grab the current post.

Also, I don't think you can simply tuck `$question` inside a link. Is there a different way this should be written?

This may be one of those situations where I don't know what I don't know, which makes finding an answer challenging. Thanks for any insight you can provide.

Comment: can you paste your full **Error Message** here ?

Comment: I just added `the_meta;` to my code just before `$question` and now the key and value each display in a bulleted list. That's kind of progress! But, of course, it doesn't do what I want just yet: hide the URL and turn the question into a link. This is the error message: "Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_field() in /home/lovesmoo/public_html/wp-content/themes/moose/functions.php on line 255"

Answer (score 0):

```
Pass post id in function 
add_action('genesis_entry_content', 'moose_question');
 function moose_question($post_id) {
     $question = get_field('question', $post_id);
     $link = get_field('link', $post_id);
     echo '<div class="moose-question">';
     echo '<a href="$link">$question</a>';
     echo '</div>';
    }
```

Comment: How does this works? `echo '<a href="$link">$question</a>';`

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't work. I added `the_meta;` just before `$question` in my code and that resulted in the key and value printing to my site. But I'm getting an error message. The error message remains the same even when I added `$post_id` to the function just before `$question.`

Answer (score 0):

And we have success. I can now output the key as a linked question, using the URL from the second key I created.

I ran into a couple of challenges during this process.

1) I inadvertently commented out my function and everything that follows, due to not having added a second forward slash. Duh.

2) I capitalized the key when I created it, but I didn't capitalize Question in the function. As soon as I corrected this, the function worked.

I learned that you can add HTML directly inside the custom field value box. But with this updated code, below, I now have a tidier way to do this. Thank you, Brad Dalton, and Bob from the WordPress forums. Your help, when pieced together, helped me resolve this problem.

```
add_action('genesis_entry_content', 'moose_question');
function moose_question() {
if ( !is_page() ) {

$question = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'question', true );
$link = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'link', true );

if( ! empty( $question ) ) {

echo '<div class="moose-question">';
echo '<a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank">'.$question.'</a>';
echo '</div>';

}}}
```